# How to set List<String> in textView on android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my application i have `List<String>` and i want show each of `strings` into this List show in `textView` and split with **,** character.

**For example :** my `List<String>` data is = **["Mobile", "Tablet, "Pc"]** . i want set this `strings` into `textView` .

I want use this into `RecyclerView` **adapter**. I write below codes, but just show last `string` into `TextView`

**My Codes:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.txtTitle.setText(list.get(position).getTitle());
    if (list.get(position).getIsSet()) {
        if (list.get(position).getDesc().size() > 0) {
            for (String desc : list.get(position).getDesc()) {
                holder.txtState.setText(desc);
            }
        }

    } else {
        holder.txtState.setText("Not selected");

    }

    holder.profileEditListLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        Intent intent = new Intent(App.currentActivity, TesterProfileFilterActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("MACHINE_STATE", list.get(position).getId());
        App.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);

    });
}
```

When use above codes, just show **Pc** in `textview`

How can i it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [android.text.TextUtils.join()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils#join(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Iterable))

`holder.txtState.setText(TextUtils.join(", ", list.get(position).getDesc()));`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following the way

```
StringBuffer br=new StringBuffer(); 
    for (String desc : list.get(position).getDesc()) {

            br.append(desc )

                }
     holder.txtState.setText(br.toString());
```

Or you can use the simplest way

```
String textdata = String.join(",", list.get(position).getDesc());
 holder.txtState.setText(textdata );
```

Comment: Thanks dear, but i used StringBuilder bud add all desc in each of rows . but your code is true. what is deference between StringBuilder with StringBuffer ?

Comment: now you can check my updated answer use the second approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.join` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Mobile");
    list.add("Tablet");
    list.add("PC");
    /*
     * join the Strings from the list to a comma separated String
     * and enclose them in brackets
     */
    System.out.println("[" + String.join(", ", list) + "]");
}
```

The output would be

```
[Mobile, Tablet, PC]
```

In your case, you would have to write

```
holder.txtState.setText("[" + String.join(", ", list.get(position).getDesc()) + "]");
```

in order to get all the items displayed in the `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your text inside `TextView` inside the loop.

Should be like:

```
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    for (String desc : list.get(position).getDesc()) {
                    ssb.append(desc);
                    ssb.append("\n");
                }
    holder.txtState.setText(ssb.toString());
```